# How to install libboost 1.54 on Debian?

Tags: debian, c++, boost

How is it possible to install libboost-dev Version 1.54 on Debian?

It automatically installs 1.55 but I need to have the particular version mentioned.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to explain *why* you need an earlier version? You'll get better help if you can explain what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can download [libboost-dev_1.54.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/154303965/libboost-dev_1.54.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) from **launchpad** and install it using dpkg.